# Changing Windows paths within application to Linux path for container use

Tags: linux, windows, sed, path, containers

I have an application that has at least one hard coded Windows path. The application now has to run in a container with Linux OS. When trying to write a file with this (Windows) path, the application crashes. The command the app is using is `writeToFile(args)`. For multiple reasons I cannot modify the application at the moment (I will be able to in the future). I am trying to work out what I can do to have this application run in a Linux OS container for now.

I tried `sed` command in the Dockerfile like so: `RUN echo 'abc\def\ghi\\file-name.txt' | sed 's#\\#/#g'`

When Dockerfile is being built, I see the proper link being printed on the console like this: abc/def/ghi//file-name.txt, but when I run the container, I see the same error in the container log:

> .FileNotFoundException: abc\def\ghi\file-name.txt (Permission denied)

Is there a proper way to solve this issue temporarily until I can make edits to the application directly?

Comment: Can you just symlink `abc\def\ghi\file-name.txt` to `abc/def/ghi/file-name.txt` (making sure to create the dirs first)?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that (`ln -s abc\def\ghi\file-name.txt
 abc/def/ghi/file-name.txt`) but it didn't work in my case. Possibly because the file doesn't exist until the app starts to write it. The app is in fact creating the file at runtime.

Comment: That command has the arguments swapped and fails to escape the backslashes. Please verify with `ls -l` that you successfully create the symlink as intended, and that you can successfully write to it with something like `echo foo > 'abc\def\ghi\file-name.txt'` before you try to run the application. Obviously this needs to happen inside the container.

Comment: @thatotherguy, thanks! I was able to change the Windows link in the app and now it's `abc/def/filename.txt`, but is throwing a similar error (FileNotFoundException: abc/def/filename.txt (No such file or directory)). 

This is how symbolic link is created in the Dockerfile: 

`RUN ln -s "$PWD/abc/def/filename.txt" abc/def/filename.txt`

To follow your advice after the container started, I checked the link with `ls -l`. From the folder where the file is created in the container - this is what the command returned: 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root date filename.txt -> //filename.txt

Comment: Sounds like you've now edited the application and no longer need this temporary solution to trick the application into opening a path with Windows directory separators.